# Restore Windows 7 But Raid1

Tags: windows-7, windows, raid

I have a remote pc running win7 with RAID setting; RAID1.

Am I able to do system restore as right now user complaint newly installed application slows down the system.

As my friend suggest, need to pull out one of the sata cable and change mode to IDE. Is this true the only way?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't true.

My primary home computer is a desktop that was installed with Windows 7 in a RAID 1 configuration (two 1 TB hard drives) for several years, and I used the System Restore function without any problems.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was restored with no problem.

Comment: If that's the case, you can submit your own answer describing what you did and mark it as the officially accepted version so that people who search for this in the future will have a good reference.